# is_int() cannot check $_GET in PHP?

Tags: php, get, integer

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET["id"];

if (is_int($id) === FALSE)  {
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    exit('404, page not found');
    }
?>
```

It always enters inside the if.

Comment: And `$_GET` actually contains... what?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`is_int` checks that the *data type* is an integer, but everything in `$_GET` will be a *string.* Therefore, it will always return `false`.

In a pinch, you could cast to an integer and then check for != 0.

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : null;

if (!$id) { // === 0 || === null
  header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
  exit('404, page not found');
}
```

But a more robust solution would involve some type of input string validation / filtering, like PHP's built-in `filter_input_array()`.

(Edited post on Oct/13 since it is still receiving upvotes and it was somewhat confusingly worded.)

Comment: Ran out of upvotes for the day, but this answer actually says the reason why to use is_numeric. Any HTTP request parameter sent by POST or GET will always be a string.

Comment: +1 - though to be mentioned, `is_numeric` does not have the same effect, as it e.g. also lets hex-values pass besides others (see php.net)

Comment: @Helmut, yes, `is_numeric()` is not proper for checking integer ids. In practice, all user input should be passed through `filter_var()` or some other similarly explicit routine.

Answer (score 5):

User input in $_GET array (as well as the other superglobals) all take the form of strings.

[`is_int`](http://php.net/is_int) checks the *type* (i.e. `string`) of the value, not whether it contains integer-like values.  For verification that the input is an integer string, I would suggest either something like [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/ctype_digit) or an integer [filter](http://php.net/filter) (`FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`—this has the benefit of actually changing the value to type integer). Of course you could also typecast it with `(int)`.

Answer (score 3):

From the PHP documentation for is_int:

> Note: To test if a variable is a
>   number or a numeric string (such as
>   form input, which is always a string),
>   you must use [is_numeric()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).

Answer (score 1):

Any user input comes in as a string, because PHP has no way to tell what data type you expect the data to be.

Cast it to an integer or use a regex if you want to make sure it's an integer.

```
<?php
$id = $_GET["id"];

if ((int) $id == 0)  {
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    exit('404, page not found');
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `is_numeric` instead of `is_int`. `is_numeric` checks to see if it is given something that can be a number (`$_GET` returns strings I think). `is_int` checks to see if the variable is of type `int`

Answer (score 0):

**Use [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)** to evaluate the content and  is_int() to evaluate the type.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could just use a regex match to check if the string is an integer.

```
if(preg_match('/^\d+$/',$_GET['id'])) {
  // is an integer
}
```