# Php: redirect to page 1 if url $page value is not integers in pagination

Tags: php

So, I have a pagination project where I have to check if the $Page variable is  (not set) , my challenge is how can i redirect to page 1 if url $page variable is not integers

(example, /my_pagination.php?Page=[six]&txtKeyword=)

instead of (example, /my_pagination.php?Page=[6]&txtKeyword=).

This what i have tried but my pagination stops going to other pages and stays on page one. Am i need of assistance.

```
$Page= 1;

        if(isset($_GET['Page'])){// Checks if the $Page variable is not integers )  
            $Page= preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['Page']);
        }`
```

and here is my original code

```
 if(!isset($_GET['Page'])){ // Checks if the $page variable is empty (not set)  
    $Page = 1;     // If it is empty, we're on page 1  
} else{  

    $Page = $_GET['Page'];  
}
```

Comment: You need to tell the webbrowser it needs to go to another page with something like: ```header("Location: /" + $Page );```

Comment: ^ Although note that `header()` won't work if you have any content outputted to the DOM before trying to call it :)

Answer (score 0):

To check if a variable is an integer you can use `is_int()` which will return `TRUE` or `FALSE` http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php
Please note that you might want to validate anything from the `$_GET` variable, because it is untrustworthy (user input).

Also anything in `$_GET` is ALWAYS a string.
=> [is_int() cannot check $_GET in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135068/is-int-cannot-check-get-in-php)

For this reason I would use `is_numeric()` instead. 
=> http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

If you absolutely have to have an integer, you can use a combination of both functions.

As Benjamin Close mentioned in the comments, you can use the `header()` function for a redirect. http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_GET['page'] ) && is_numeric( $_GET['page'] ) ) {
        $page   = (int) $_GET['page'];
        //build url based on int based page number
        $url    = 'http://yourdomain.tld/page.php?numbers=' . $page;
    } else {
        $page   = $_GET['page'];
        //build url based on text based page number
        $url    = 'http://yourdomain.tld/page.php?letters=' . $page;
    }
    header('Location: '. $url );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url doesn't look like pagination; typically you have a page, and then you have a way to paginate the content of the page. You shouldn't redirect to a page; you should compute the content and display the part of the content associated with the page. Pages are typically not real pages; they're part of the content of a single long page.

```
page = foo.php

/foo.php?page=$page

of

/foo.php/PAGE  (ie /foo.php/1 /foo.php/2 etc)
```

How your pages are paginated is part of your design. One technique is to use  markers. Suppose you have a long page of text with

```
<page>
```

markers to delineate where the pages are broken.

```
$pages = explode('<page>',$pageContent);

$pages now have your pages in an array from 0 -> $page-1 

So for Example you could do:

// url = /foo.php?page=3

// You have to handle the case of /foo.php where no page is specified

$page = intval($_GET['page']);  // intval will return 0 if page is empty
if ($page < 1)
    $page = 1;
$thisContent = $pages[$page-1];

// display $thisContent
```